# Narrowing a generic return type

Tags: typescript

I have a function that's a bit like this:

```
function getOutput<TInputType>(input: TInputType): TInputType {
    if (typeof input === 'string') {
        return 'abc';
    } else {
        return input;
    }
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQPIigB2wHgBUBJMPKQgTx1QD4AKGM7ALkROYutQEo2PyVGogDeAKESTEMYInpRucWU3KIAvBsQByAM5QATk2RaeoiVIv70IfUi0BDAEYQtAbnOSAvolQAbHahmFpbWttKc7haeYtFAA)

This code has a TS error on the third line: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'TInputType'.`

But since we check that `typeof input` is `string`, then by returning `'abc'` we are returning the same type as `input`. But it seems TS isn't able to infer that in this case.

Is there a way to make TS happy here? (other than casting, @ts-ignore, and friends)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript is correct to report an error. Consider the function call `getOutput<'xyz'>('xyz')`. According to the function's definition, the return type should be `'xyz'` since that's what the type parameter `TInputType` is for this call. However, the code as written actually returns `'abc'`, which is not assignable to the type `'xyz'`.

So there is no way to "make Typescript happy" with this code short of using intentionally unsound behaviour like a type assertion or `@ts-ignore`, because the code itself *is* unsound.

Answer (score 0):

You can add [function overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) to distinguish two situations better:

```js
function getOutput(input: string): string;
function getOutput<P>(input: P): P;
function getOutput<P, T extends string | P>(input: T): T | string {
    if (typeof input === 'string') {
        return 'abc';
    } else {
        return input;
    }
}

const iAmString = getOutput('a'); // string
const iAmAnything = getOutput(2 + 3); // number
const iAmAnythingElse = getOutput(new Date()); // Date
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQPIigB2wChjDygC5EBnKAJyOQEpyraxkBuAKFElgRXSy5sAHgAKAPkLFs5UY0SjO3aPCRpM2EmIA0iACqJUADyiowAEwqUadRAB8FkoiXJ75Bh81sBvDon+IMMCI+FAAnjiocMHO2IgAvImIAORerMn0iL4BOYjU6CDUSMkAhgBGEMmcOQC+hgA2FKhZfrn++VCFSLFQ1QE1HAMcEAhUgQCCALYAyjasCfwaQlD4pRlsiAD0m9YsyMOjUBOT42BhUAAWtvGLgiT4AEyIANSIAMz0G9uIYCCTZahqAcwGMYFNTucrqwAKKNZo3dR3AhgVAAd0QABESqZ8PRPlsdljTEA)

Comment: This errors with TS 4.4.2 in playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQPIigB2wChjDygC5EAVASWOwoE8dUBKc62qBpxAbwChEgxDGCJ8URqjiiiJRAF5FiAOQBnKACciyZc14ChhjehAakygIYAjCMoDcBwQF9EqADarU+w0ZNnhHA6GTnwhQA

Comment: Can you be more specific about the type itself? It would help. If type `TInputType = string | number` it works for example.

Comment: It can be anything, no restrictions.

Comment: `type TInputType = any;` still works. It needs a type definition.

Comment: I'd like TInputType to be a generic type parameter, not just `any`, `any` is cheating, though I'll go there if there are no other options.

Comment: I've managed to do what you want and edited the answer

Comment: This has the same problem as described in my answer; function overloads allow for unsound behaviour, so this isn't really a better alternative to a type assertion or `@ts-ignore`.